# Angular 10 set visibility on Route Change

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application that I'm trying to change the available options on the navigation component based on the route.  I had this working using something like this:

```
*ngIf="router.url.split('?')[0].split('#')[0] === '/home'"
```

However, I'm making some updates and the logic is a bit more complex so I'd rather not do it in the HTML like that.  I tried subscribing to router events and setting properties but it doesn't seem to be working.  Here is my init method for the component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.scroller.setOffset([0, 98]);
    this.authService.UserIsAdmin.subscribe(admin => this.UserIsAdministrator = admin);

    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationStart))
      .subscribe((e: NavigationEnd) => {
        const isHome = e.url.split('?')[0].split('#')[0] === '/home';
        this.ShowStandardItems = isHome;
        this.ShowAdminItems = this.UserIsAdministrator && (isHome || Constants.AdminRoutes.indexOf(e.url) !== -1);
        this.ShowHome = this.ShowAdminItems && !isHome;
        console.log(`${this.ShowStandardItems}/${this.ShowHome}/${this.ShowAdminItems}`);
      });
  }
```

And an example binding in the html:

```
  <a routerLink="/customer-management" [class.currentPage]="router.url === '/customer-management'"
     *ngIf="ShowAdminItems">
    CUSTOMERS
  </a>
```

Lastly the field definition in the ts file:

```
public ShowStandardItems = false;
```

I have the console log in there at the end and I can see that it's setting those properties correctly and hitting the event handler but nothing ever shows up on my UI, none of the items are visible.  If I change their default value to true then they show up even if they are not supposed to, so it's just not updating the UI based on those properties.

I have also tried subscribing only to `NavigationEnd`, subscribing in the constructor instead of `ngOnInit`, but neither made any difference.

The really strange thing is that if I force certain ones to always be on and then navigate from there it will suddenly start working.  It's like it doesn't pick up on the first one and then does after that...

I also should mention that the home page this goes to at first does a login and then uses router to navigate to the home page.  I have tried both `this.router.navigate()` and `this.router.navigateByUrl()` to do the navigation but it didn't make any difference.

How do I make this work?

Comment: there's a danger that **this.UserIsAdministrator** is not yet accessible in the second subscription since the second subscription could be resolved before the first one.

Comment: I thought that may be it but I don't think so after some testing.  I set the timeout on the second to 5 seconds so it updates those a full 5 seconds later and the problem persists.  Also per the logging it's setting those properties correctly, the UI is just not updating accordingly.